# Magento Calendar 1.9 show alert display its saturday n day on select date

Tags: magento-1.9, html

```
function setcal(n) {
    var dated = document.getElementById('inspectiondate' + n).value;
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField: "inspectiondate" + n,
        ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%e",
        showsTime: false,
        range: "currentYear",
        button: "Idate" + n,
        align: "Bl",
        singleClick: true,
        dateStatusFunc: function(date) {
            var now = new Date();
            if (date.getFullYear() === now.getFullYear()) {
                if (date.getMonth() < now.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear()) {
                    return (true);
                } else {
                    if (date.getDate() < now.getDate() && date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear()) return (true);
                    else return (false);
                }
            }
            onSelect: function(dateText, selectedDate) {
                alert(selectedDate);
            }
            if (date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setcal(n)
{
var dated= document.getElementById('inspectiondate'+n).value;
                Calendar.setup({
                    inputField: "inspectiondate"+n,
                    ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%e",
                    showsTime: false,
                    range:"currentYear",
                    button: "Idate"+n,
                    align: "Bl",
                    singleClick : true,
                    onSelect: function(dateText,selectedDate) {
                        dateText.hide();
                            jQuery("#inspectiondate"+n).val(selectedDate);
                    console.log(dateText.date.getDay());

                    if(dateText.date.getDay()==0 || dateText.date.getDay()==6)  {
                        if(confirm("Your selected date the day is a Saturday or Sunday, \n do you wish to continue?!")){

                            return true;

                        }
                        else{

                            jQuery("#inspectiondate"+n).val("");
                            return false;

                        }

                    }
                    },

                    dateStatusFunc :    function (date) { 
                                var now= new Date();

                                if(date.getFullYear() === now.getFullYear())
                                { 


                                    if(date.getMonth() < now.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear())
                                    {
                                        return (true);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                         if(date.getDate() < now.getDate() && date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear())
                                             return (true);
                                         else
                                             return (false);
                                    }
                                }

                                }


                });                                     

}
```